# How to make an excel report on android?

Tags: android, excel

I need to make a simple Excel report from an android application. I'm using "jlx.jar" but I don´t know how I can save the excel on the phone.

```
WriteExcel test = new WriteExcel();
            String path = getBaseContext().getFilesDir().getPath();
            test.setOutputFile(path);
            try {
                test.write();

            } catch (WriteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

I get a FileNotFoundException. The path is "/data/data/mypackage/files/"

Don't think there's a problem here, but here's the write() method:

```
public void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
        WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        createLabel(excelSheet);
        createContent(excelSheet);

        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
      }
```

Comment: you are giving it a path for a directory where I would rather expect a file.(try to add a filename to your path)

Comment: in your create workbook, you are passing file, what is the value?

Comment: The same as the path, which is "/data/data/mypackage/files/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you are following this tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html

when you setOutputFile you do,

```
public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
  this.inputFile = inputFile;
  }
```

but when you are passing value to inputFile you are passing

```
String path = getBaseContext().getFilesDir().getPath();
            test.setOutputFile(path);
```

path here is just `the path to a directory` and `not a file`

append your `filename(test.xls)` to the `path variable`

as in the tutorial

```
test.setOutputFile("c:/temp/lars.xls");
```